Unable to trigger listeners in bloc event integration test
I'm doing an integration test, where I want to trigger an event change after a submit button. below is my setup for the test as well as the actual test, I've tried multiple ways and positions to set the setEntriesSavedSate, I'm also using a streamcontroller to controll the stream, but the listeners on my widget is never getting called.
class HabitsBlocFixture {
  final mockHabitsBloc = MockHabitsBloc();
  // Create a single stream controller for the bloc
  final _streamController = StreamController<HabitsNewState>.broadcast();

  void setupCommonMocks() {
    registerFallbackValue(FakeHabitEntrySave());
    when(() => mockHabitsBloc.close()).thenAnswer((_) async => Future.value());
    when(() => mockHabitsBloc.stream).thenAnswer((_) => _streamController.stream);
    when(() => mockHabitsBloc.add(any())).thenAnswer((_) async => {});
  }

  void setEntriesSavedState() {
    final savedState = HabitsNewState(
      status: HabitStatus.entriesSaved,
      habitsWithEntries: sampleHabitsWithEntries,
      error: null,
    );

    print('Setting up saved state with status: ${savedState.status}');
    when(() => mockHabitsBloc.state).thenReturn(savedState);
    
    // Add the state to the stream
    print('Emitting saved state');
    _streamController.add(savedState);
    print('State emitted');
  }

  void dispose() {
    _streamController.close();
  }
}

Test:
testWidgets('Can select a habit and save entry', (tester) async {
      await integrationBase.pumpAndSettleApp(tester, isUserLoggedIn: true, isHabitsLoaded: true);
      integrationBase.habitsBlocFixture.setLoadedState();

      // Tap the add entry button to show dialog
      await tester.tap(find.byIcon(Icons.add));
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();

      // Tap on a habit in the CupertinoBottomDialog
      await tester.tap(
        find.descendant(
          of: find.byType(HabitEntryDialogCupertino),
          matching: find.text('meditation'),
        ),
      );
      await tester.pump();

      // Set the saved state BEFORE tapping Done
      integrationBase.habitsBlocFixture.setEntriesSavedState();

      // Tap done button and pump just once
      await tester.tap(find.text('Done'));
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();

      // Verify success message
      expect(find.text("Way to go! You've added a new habit entry."), findsOneWidget);
    });

